# Idiomatic way to trigger tasks in GraphQL

Tags: migration, graphql

In a REST API, you might have an endpoint like:

`/trigger_job/<job_id: int>`

which returns:

`{'ok': True, 'message': 'run complete'}`

In GraphQL you could use something like:

```
mutation runJob($job: Int) {
   triggerJob(jobID: $job) {
       ok
       message
   }
}
```

to represent the same task.  Would this be considered an idiomatic way to use GraphQL for command and control, or is there a different method for migrating non schema-based endpoints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In GraphQL we have queries, which are supposed to be free of (write) side effects and which as well makes them idempotent in the sense of the word used for HTTP requests. And for operations that change the state of the server we (have to) use mutations. They are probably closer to [RPCs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) than to REST and therefore much more flexible in what they represent. I often like to think about mutations as just functions.

In fact I would argue that your REST example is not idiomatic because you are trying to trigger an action while REST (literally Representational State Transfer) only allows you to transfer state. So yes, I think your way is pretty much idiomatic because I don't think you can do a lot wrong with GraphQL here. GraphQL does not really have a strong opinion on that.

Two little things on schema design: If your amount of available jobs is small you might consider using an enum to select the job instead of an int. This allows developers to know which jobs are available without having to look into the database. If this is good design really depends on what your jobs are in your system but it might be worth considering. Also, a mutation usually would allow you to fetch the changed state afterwards using a field on the result type. I am not sure if this is feasable in your case.